# MySql create temporary table from source table without indexes

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to "duplicate" a table from my db creating a temporary one. However I need indexes are not copied.

I'm using this query right now:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp365 LIKE contactlens;
```

but the result table contains also indexes. I checked out the documentation and I don't see a way to copy the structure without indexes.
Because I can't have static name for indexes, I was wondering how I can drop all of them using simple SQL.

I was starting trying to avoid to copy them at all, but it seems not possible.

Comment: Use [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score 6):

It's just to provide some examples to [@wchiquito's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53457445/mysql-create-temporary-table-from-source-table-without-indexes#comment93786979_53457445).

It's pretty easy to create a copy of a table without indexes using [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) command.

If you don't need to copy any rows from original table just provide a false value in WHERE clause or specify 0 in LIMIT one. Some examples:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] temp365 SELECT * FROM contactlens WHERE 0;
```

or a bit different way:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] temp365 SELECT * FROM contactlens LIMIT 0;
```

This way you'll get the same result as with [CREATE TABLE ... LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-like.html), but without indexes.